# I want to change the resolution division in smoke simulation but can't find it

Tags: mesh, particles, remesh

I'm trying to do a smoke simulation and I want to make the smoke to have more resolution division but can't find it. I watched some tutorial, that's why I'm asking or am I missing something?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You have to set the _Resolution Divisions_ on the domain object. From the shape I would have assumed this is your domain, but the settings in your screenshot say this is the _Flow_ object.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBk7YSfJLOw&t=599s&ab_channel=CGGeek at 15:50 that what confused me here u know but i got what u mean

Comment: Yeah, well I don't know what confuses you there. Steve says he's going to add a smoke **domain**, then the adds the cube and after clicking on the _Smoke_ physics button he shows and says "and then we're gonna choose the type to be **_Domain_**". You have switched it to _Flow_, so please tell me what exactly was so confusing in Steve's explanation.

Comment: I think Its all about the old blender vs new blender maybe what confused me is the smoke that i could not  see in physics tab unless I Put fluid and other settings , anyway thanks for the reply even though Im Not actually new to blender but sometimes u forget something and you guys always helpful , much respect